# Idiom or pattern for N concurrent readers and 1 producer

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11

Using the C++11 standard library (with the only help of `boost::thread` eventually) is there a clean way to implement a N readers - 1 producer solution, where all the readers, once notified at the same time (with `std::condition_variable::notify_all()` for example) by the producer, are guaranteed to enter their critical section before the producer will eventually enter its critical section a second time. In other words, all the notified readers must observe the same state of the shared resource. Once the producer noties the N readers, it cannot modify the shared resource until all the N readers have finished their reading. Note that boost::barrier is not really what I need, as I do not know N in advance. N may vary from one notification to another.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [atomic counters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic), with some polling from the producer thread.

When the counter reaches either `N` or `0` (it's up to you) then the producer gets to work and produce whatever it needs to produce. Before notifying the condition variable, the producers sets the counter to `0` (or `N`).

When a reader is done, it simply increases (or decreases) the counter.

Comment: It does not work with one counter: what happens if *new* readers come after the producer notifies the waiting readers? If the new readers (atomically) increase the same counter that "older" readers are decreasing, the producer might never wake up.

Comment: @Martin The count down to zero. If a new reader appears (or disappears) then simply increase (or decrease) `N`, then have a check for less or equal zero in the producer.

Comment: I still don't see how increasing/decreasing the counter that way solves my problem. Suppose 2 readers are waiting. The producer notifies them all, so N becomes 2. The first reader decreases the counter, N=1. Ok. Now if a third reader arrives it should not increase the counter, since it does not belong to the group of two readers. It should wait a second notification from the producer, which can only start after the second reader finishes its job.

Comment: @Martin Two variables: The actual counter, and the number of readers. When a new reader is started it increases the number of readers, when it ends it decreases the number. When the producer is ready to signal all readers it sets the counter to the _current_ number of readers.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called a [barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers)

Comment: It's "almost" a barrier, as I don't know how many readers (N is not fixed) will be waiting when the producer notifies them. I'll make the question more clear about this point, thanks.